# How to make a table from a class nesting dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a table to do fuzzy string matching with data pulled from HubSpot database. Luckily I found a library which allows me to connect to the server through RESTful API.

The results that I get look like:

```
from hubspot.connection import APIKey, PortalConnection
from hubspot.contacts.lists import get_all_contacts
    authentication_key = APIKey("your key")
    with PortalConnection(authentication_key, "Your App Name") as connection:
        for contact in get_all_contacts(connection):

Contact(vid=1, email_address=u'foo@example.com', properties={u'lastname': u'Smith', u'company': u'ACME Ltd.', u'firstname': u'John', u'lastmodifieddate': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 15, 32, 7, 192000)}, related_contact_vids=[])
Contact(vid=2, email_address=u'bar@example.com', properties={u'lastname': u'Doe', u'company': u'Example Inc.', u'firstname': u'Alice', u'lastmodifieddate': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 29, 15, 37, 52, 447000)}, related_contact_vids=[])
```

Then I try to create a table. I used pandas DataFrame to create a table but it seems like frames were created for each instance respectively although what I wanted was one table for whole records. I also tried to merge them but it was unsuccessful. No error message appears now but I am stuck...

Here's the code that I tried.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([contact.properties], columns = ['lastname', 'firstname'])
df['email'] = contact.email_address

frame = pd.concat([new_df], axis=0, join='outer', keys=None, levels=None)
print frame
```

the result looks like...

```
  lastname firstname           email
0    Soans     Ralf  rawe@example.com
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [lastname, firstname, email]
Index: []
  lastname firstname           email
0  Parsons    Han    hnps@example.com
  lastname firstname           email
0  Stanton           sfjlwe@example.com
```

What I wanted was more like

```
  lastname firstname           email
0    Soans     Ralf  rawe@example.com
0  Parsons    Han    hnps@example.com
0  Stanton           sfjlwe@example.com
```

I don't understand why `Columns: [lastname, firstname, email]
Index: []` keeps repeating as well. I am quite a newbie in programming, so I am not sure if I get closer to the goal or if my approach makes sense or not.
I use Python 2.7 Any opinion would be helpful!!!

Comment: It seems like `contact.properties` is a single line in your table - is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edit this seems like it would work directly:

```
pd.DataFrame([contact.properties for contact in get_all_contacts(connection)])
```

If you have a list of dictionaries with the same keys Pandas is smart enough to use keys as column names and the values to build said columns.

Comment: Thank you for leaving your answer! Really worried if nobody shows interest;) Sorry that I didn't explain how I get contacts clearly. I use RESTful API generated in HubSpot(it is a CRM application!) and loads of records are pulled from its server.

Comment: @ywywyw Either edit your question to show an [MCVE] - giving an example list of contacts after you have them locally, or use my solution modified to create said property list, as noted in the comment. My solution is straight forward enough - given a list of contact properties, this will work.

Comment: Just edited my question to explain more on how I get the contacts.

Comment: I tried your solution and it looks much better! Thanks! But still seems like data frames are created for each instance. Now it looks like..                       
company firstname        lastmodifieddate lastname
0  Dxxx     Rxxx 2018-08-16 03:12:52.977    Sxxx
   firstname        lastmodifieddate
0  Gxxx 2018-08-16 03:12:52.996
  firstname        lastmodifieddate lastname
0    Hxxx 2018-08-16 03:12:53.149  Pxxx

Comment: @ywywyw I can't read that last comment. I fixed my answer to build a list from what you edited into your question.